# Regex - Match If Not Before a Character

Tags: c#, regex

I have this regexp: `(?!\.)\bSize\b(?!")`

I am trying to match the word "Size" but ignore it if it is preceded by a dot (.) I tried different variations but I keep getting this result : [image: Result]

How can I create a regex to do this?

Comment: Depends on what regex extensions you're using. Strictly speaking, lookbehind can't exist in a regular expression.

Comment: Thanks for reading and replying, can you please elaborate? I'm using it for C# tho I need to solve it using regex if possible.

Comment: Size not preceded by a dot = `(?<!\.)Size`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're confusing the negative lookahead and negative lookbehind assertions. You probably want `(?<!\.)\bSize\b(?!")`.
As I stated in the comments though, this is dependent on your regex extensions, as lookahead/behind assertions cannot exist in true regular expressions.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx) is the documentation for regular expressions in C#.

Comment: Yeah but C# uses lookbehind assertions.

Comment: @sln It was initially unknown what Regex engine was being used. If it was a more restrictive engine, such as re2, these sort of constructs aren't supported.

Comment: re2 is primitive, built for speed not variability.